# Use native Calling and Chat API in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, twilio, sinch

I am building a dating app in xamarin forms. Everything is setup like login,peoples profiles ,payments etc. But now i got stuck on implementing voice call and chat functionality.
There are many library available of native IOS and android like Sinch,Twillio they are not available for xamarin forms. Is there any way of using these library (Specially sinch api).
I tried to achieve it using binding feature available in xamarin but end up with failure. As binding feature only useful in case AAR(Android archive) or Jar library. I was looking for some example or guidance where something like calling/chat/image editor (i.e. where UI and coding involve) has been implemented in xamarin by using native API.

Comment: search up on tcp-client in .net. you can create your chat functionality with that. its bascially a connection between the device and the server which constantly streams updates

Comment: Yes i can use SingalR for chat ,But my concern is using native api/sdk proided for android or IOS in xamarine forms by converting them into .net compatible

Comment: you can use the tcp client api in the underlying platforms (android, ios, uwp). is that what you mean? Xamarin is converting it to the native code

Comment: I know customers that have written their own plugins for xamarin using sinch, but its unsupported.

Comment: is there any sinch github file available for xamarin forms, please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SendBird](https://sendbird.com/) Messaging SDK and Chat API for Mobile Apps and Websites.

It has [support for Xamarin](https://docs.sendbird.com/dotnet) officially and It has a nuget package **NOT OFFICIAL** for Xamarin.Forms It's works perfectly you can download [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.SendBird/)

Additionally, you can use this [sample on Github](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/SendBird-Xamarin) that use this nuget package.

> This answer is not spam. It's only a recommendation

Comment: SendBird is another API that is helpful but this is paid. Now I am using singnaR for chat and sinch API for calling. Xamarin .Net Implemtation of sinch API can be found from here https://github.com/NAXAM/sinch-rtc-android-binding

Answer (score 2):

You can use CometChat Xamarin SDK, It fits your above requirements perfectly. It has Audio/Video call functionalities builtin along with Audio/video broadcast & screen share. For more information you can check out the documentation at the following link:

https://developer.cometchat.com/docs/xamarin-forms-quick-start